# Does "ne pas" and "ne pas que" have the same meaning in this context? Can you use both?

Tags: grammaire, sens, choix-de-mot, négation

- On n’a pas fait tout ce chemin pour se tourner les pouces.
- On n’a pas fait tout ce chemin que pour se tourner les pouces.

At least, I understand that the first sentence sounds natural, but can the second sentence be used as well? Or should you use "seulement"?

- On n’a pas fait tout ce chemin seulement pour se tourner les pouces.
- On n’a pas fait tout ce chemin, seulement pour se tourner les pouces.

Answer (score 3):

(ne) pas que is the negative of que.
(ne) pas is just the negative.

Il n'en a qu'une - He only has one.
Il n'en a pas qu'une - He doesn't only have one.

Don't get confused by the 'ne'. Que by itself is considered a negative. ne que does not mean 'not only'. It means 'only'. Just like ne pas doesn't mean not not, it just means not.

In colloquial French, ne can be dropped. It's just a dummy word that has no meaning.

In your example, the sentence with que just adds the meaning 'only'. In answer to your question, no they are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

As a French native, both sentence feel natural and I would understand them.

Adding the "que" really emphasizes that it's ONLY to "se tourner les pouces".

You could also say :

- On n'a pas fait tout ce chemin juste pour se tourner les pouces.

Hope it helps !